# when I try to upload a file in git

Tags: github

When I push a file to git it gives an error

`git push origin master`

error:

> src refspec master does not match any

error:

> failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/raja*******/new-folder.git'

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`git push origin master --force`

If the branches are not in sync try pulling and pushing -

```
git pull
git push -u origin master
```

This problem can also arise if you have not made any commits, use

```
git commit -m "Commit Message"
git push origin master
```

Try git show-ref to see what refs you have. Is there a refs/heads/master?
If you have switched to main from master then all these commands will not work.

Try this

`git push origin HEAD:master`

Comment: Are both the branches synced properly or are there any differences between the two

Comment: I have already run that command git commit -m "Commit Message"

Comment: Try reinitializing your git repository. git init => git add -A => git commit => git push origin master

Comment: I have tried pulling and pushing the error is still same

Comment: I have reinitialized my git repository the error still same

Comment: git show-ref
978cdd28784658edb530a09f90a0a94db1ad3686 refs/heads/main

it's in main only